# Подскажите ка смоделировать деталь мотоцикла в Blender 3D

Tags: 3d, blender, моделирование

Всем привет.
Я начал изучать Blender и столкнулся с деталью, которую никак не могу смоделировать.
[image: Деталь]

[тут](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/harley-davidson-motorcycle-576a0ff6ac354522bd617326f083474b) полная модель мотоцикла.
Подскажите - как смоделировать такую деталь? Какими модификаторами это можно сделать? Как бы вы сделали ее?

Comment: Так же, как и любую другую. Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Ну как бы вы сделали? какие шаги? Т.е. можно например вначале обрисовать контуры и использовать средство Grid fill. Или можно по отдельности смоделировать левую и праву часть, но тогда не понятно как создать соединяющую их поверхность. Я пробовал оба метода и в первом случае получилось не очень, а во втором не понятно как соединить две части так, чтобы красиво было